# How to run npm install on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have recently switched to a Mac from windows.
I installed node and npm.
after cloning my repo with almost code in mean. How should I install node modules I mean `npm install` `npm start` nothing really works.
so are there different commands for Mac can someone really help me out with documentation or video that may help me migrating.

Comment: Make sure you have installed everything your project needs in the new computer, and check the version of node and react you have are compatible, also does the terminal is giving you any error messages that could help to find out what is missing.

Comment: You installed node and npm _how_? Because on Mac/linux you want to use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm similar to how on Windows you want to use https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have them installed and you have **configured paths in your command line**. An easy way to install with command line compatibility is to use Homebrew. If you install homebrew, you can run `brew install node; brew install npm`

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether node and npm installed correctly on your mac.

To check node:-

```
node -v
```

To check npm:-

```
npm -v
```

If not, please install it again it should work